# What is the difference between these jquery selector sentences

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm quite confusing about these 3 usage of jquery selector sentences. All three seem like they are going to select tag `p` with class `intro`. How come there are 3 different selector sentences?

```
$("p").filter(".intro")

$("p.intro")

$("p .intro")
```

Comment: No the third one is completely different, it will select the descendants inside of p which is having the class intro

Comment: first 2 are the same, 3rd is different...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first two end up with objects that are both `"p"` and `".intro"` (e.g. those selectors are satisfied by the exact same object).

The last one is an object that is `".intro"`, but has a parent `"p"`.

**Further explanations:**

---

```
$("p").filter(".intro")
```

Get all `"p"` elements.  Then reduce that set to only the ones that are also `".intro"`.

---

```
$("p.intro")
```

Find all objects that are both `"p"` and `".intro"` (on the same object).  No space between the different selector criteria means they must be found on the same object.

---

```
$("p .intro")
```

Find all `".intro"` objects that have a parent `"p"`.  A space between the different selector criteria means they occur at a different level of the hierarchy (e.g. not on the same object - parent, then child but any number of levels between).  To create a little symmetry with the above two, this one gives the same results as:

```
$("p").find(".intro");
```